# How to right allign charts

Tags: css, html, alignment

i am trying to allign the charts with the menu. actually their height is not same as the menu on the left..

div :

```
<nav>
  <div class="menu-item alpha"> 
  <h4><a href="index.aspx" style="color: #EDEDED">Home</a></h4>           

  <p>To Navigate to Home Page</p> 
</div>   

<div class="menu-item"> 
<h4><a href="#">KPIs</a></h4> <!-- colored bar --> 

<ul> <!-- expanding white area --> 
  <li><a href="#">Churn Rate</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Dormont Users</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Other</a></li> 
</ul> 

</div> 


</nav>
```

Div for table:

```
       <table border="1" align="right" >
  <tr>
    <th>Chart 1</th>
    <th>Chart 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line" XValueMember="Activity" YValueMembers="NumberOfStudents" YValuesPerPoint="2"></asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [FavouriteActivities]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</td>
<td>
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="FastPoint" XValueMember="Activity" YValueMembers="NumberOfStudents" YValuesPerPoint="2"></asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is what is happening :
 [image]

this is what should happen :

[image]

can you help me please?

Comment: hey can you show your css also we want to see how you are using the css....

Comment: have you tried adding `float:left;` on `<div class="menu-item alpha">`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the sidebar navigation (notice the **float** properties):

This in your CSS file

```
   menu-item alpha {float: left;}
```

and this in your PHP / ASP / HTML page:

```
  <table border="1" align="right" style="float:right;">
```

Comment: i don't get it. where to write? in the css or the div file? and in what area? its all  messy and confusing :s this is my first try , wo i am really needing help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a float to `<nav>` rather than `menu-item`, otherwise the two menu blocks will be side-by-side:

CSS -

```
nav { 
   float: left;
}

table { 
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: i don't get it. where to write? in the css or the div file? and in what area? its all messy and confusing :s this is my first try , wo i am really needing help